# Is PHP include() or JS src to include file faster?

Tags: javascript, php, html, client-side, server-side

Sometimes when I need to include the same group of elements in many web pages, I use PHP:

```
<?php include "somefile.html" ?>
```

When `somefile.html` is this:

```
<h1>TITLE</h1>
<h2>Subtitle</h2>
```

And sometimes, when I'm too lazy to use PHP and turn on my local server, I use JS:

```
<script src="somescript.js"></script>
```

When `somescript.js` is like this:

```
document.write(
    "<h1>TITLE</h1>" +
    "<h2>Subtitle</h2>"
);
```

The second version is just a tiny bit more inconvenient, but I use both ways.

However, I was wondering which way is customary and which way is faster.

I know PHP is server-side and is pre-parsed into HTML first, but even though it loads before the JS does, I don't know if it's faster. Because JS is client-side, it is parsed by the browser and might be quicker than sending a request to the server (although I'm not totally sure - tell me if I'm making incorrect inferences).

Feel free to tell me if I'm unclear and redirect me to another page that could help.

Thanks.

Comment: When you're concerned about speed: **measure it.**

Comment: Regarding "Because JS is client-side, it is parsed by the browser and might be quicker than sending a request to the server" - you still have to send a request to the server to get the original HTML and the browser then makes a SECOND request to the server to get the js include. This undoubtedly a really bad approach to what you are wanting to do, unless you absolutely couldn't use some sort of script/application on the server to dynamically populate this.

Comment: @Jon you always have the tools to measure this.  You have a modern browser do you not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second way is not only worse performance wise, it's an awful practice that could potentially erase your entire page because of how `document.write()` works. You shouldn't be using `document.write()` unless you are VERY sure you need to, which is rare. The only case I know of in which it is acceptable is for fallbacks of cdn delivered javascript. You use it to write in script tags for a local copy, like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="sys/lib/jquery.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Consider that the script you're including is on the server, so a request has to be sent for it and it must be loaded before the page can continue or finish loading. The server could have just sent that data to begin with.

Comment: It doesn't for me - plus, I could use `document.getElementById("someID").innerHTML` instead of `document.write()`

Comment: @Jon yes, that is an appropriate way of adding markup to the dom, but it is still more efficient to serve it from the server if that is where you markup comes from already (unless it makes sense to ajax for it after page load - like loading something when the user clicks a button, etc).

Answer (score 3):

The first is definitely more customary, more efficient, and faster.

These are the actions I can point out to simply count the network and i/o interactions from a very high level.

php include:

- User requests
- apache processes
- php processes from disc
- apache sends data for display

js include:

- user requests
- apache processes
- (assuming html extension is not processed by php)
- apache sends data for display
- js tells browser to include another file
- apache processes request for another file
- apache sends data for inclusion
- js process displays data

Answer (score 0):

The first method is slower for the server, and the second is slower for the client. Though, in practice, both methods should be fast enough for normal use cases. I would recommend the first method though.