# how can i make a javascript call from one function to another in same script

Tags: javascript, html

i want to add two number  six times by looping & function calling. loop execute properly but function not execute properly. here the function may not called.please help. Thanks in advance

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        var i=10;
        for(j=1;j<=6;j++) {
            var x=fun(3,4);
            document.write(x);
            i++;
        }

        function fun(var i, var j) {
            var k=i+j;
            return k;
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're writing your values in the head of the document and you have erroneous `var` in the function declaration.

Comment: `document.write` should almost never be used. If you don't know why, then it should never be used. The only good way to use `document.write` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20436093/1435655

Comment: @m59 maybe you should also explain why it should never be used or link to a resource that explains why.

Comment: @SleepDeprivedBulbasaur I disagree. That's been explained about several hundred times or more elsewhere and Google is a great tool.

Comment: Please learn to use the JavaScript console in your browser. It would quickly point where where your problem was.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
remove var keyword from function parameter 

function fun(i,j)
    {
    var k=i+j;
    return k;

    }
```

Comment: This appears to be a game of spot-the-difference, not answer. What did you change? Why should it make a difference?

Answer (score 4):

You have erroneous `var` in the function declaration ( `function fun(var i, var j)` ). This is a syntax error which prevents the execution of the script.

The correct syntax is `function fun (i, j)`.

---

Note that you're using [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) (hopefully for the purpose of the question). That's a tricky function, which can only be executed during the initial loading of the page, and which should generally be avoided. For testing a code, the best practice is usually to use `console.log` instead and open the console to see the log (you may hit <kbd>F12</kbd>).